# Oracle Parameters as Array throws "index was outside the bounds" of the array error

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

I have a problem executing an Oracle Stored Procedure with parameters in Visual Studio (C#). Parameters are array values which user select.  When I try to execute, it throws "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I cannot solve the problem.

My code below:

```
public void ExecSPWBulkInsert(string spName, object[] myObjects)
{
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
    OracleParameter[] discoveredParameters = findSPParameters(spName);
    command.Connection = oraConn;
    command.ArrayBindCount = discoveredParameters.Length ;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = spName;
    OracleParameter[] param = new OracleParameter[discoveredParameters.Length];
    ArrayList[] parameters = new ArrayList[discoveredParameters.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < discoveredParameters.Length; i++)
    {
        parameters[i] = new ArrayList();
        foreach (object obj in myObjects)
        {
            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.Name == discoveredParameters[i].ParameterName)
                {
                    parameters[i].Add(prop.GetValue(obj));
                }
            }
        }

        param[i] = new OracleParameter();
        param[i].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param[i].ArrayBindSize = new int[parameters[i].Count];
        param[i].Size = 1000;
        param[i].ParameterName = discoveredParameters[i].ParameterName;
        param[i].OracleDbType = discoveredParameters[i].OracleDbType;
        param[i].Value = parameters[i].ToArray();
        command.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
    }

    try
    {
        oraConn.Open();
        command.Transaction = oraConn.BeginTransaction();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Transaction.Commit();
        oraConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
       oraConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the two arrays `param` and `parameters`? You are never making use of the collected values. Wouldn't variables local to each iteration do?

Comment: I need two arrays because, I have to collect object member values in one array and then send them as parameters. One of these arrays is for collecting member values as an array one by one and other is for defining parameters.

Comment: So you are getting the error in the front end, right? if so why dont you just debug it and find out where you are getting it?

Comment: "I need two arrays": You are not using them in the code you are showing, though.

Comment: I get the error when I try to "execute" command. I noticed above. I debug it many times and get the same error. I couldn't find why it throws "index was out of range" error.